# Query Performance Issue - for select statement even with indexes on the table with more than 20 Trillion records

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

we have three table from which the records needs to be picked from three table namely
Accounts having 162161 records
Account_Types 6 records
Transactions having 10761247 records

Below is the tables structure

TRANSACTIONS

id  bigint(20) unsigned NO  PRI     auto_increment
transfer_number bigint(20) unsigned YES MUL
debit_credit    varchar(255)    NO  MUL
fund_type   varchar(255)    NO  MUL
fund_id bigint(20) unsigned YES MUL
currency    varchar(255)    NO
amount  decimal(20,2)   NO  MUL 0
description text    NO
other_type  varchar(255)    NO
other_id    bigint(20) unsigned YES
transaction_type    varchar(255)    NO
accounts_receivable int(1) unsigned NO      0
transaction_status  varchar(255)    NO  MUL
creation_date   datetime    NO      0000-00-00 00:00:00 
execution_date  datetime    NO  MUL 0000-00-00 00:00:00 
api int(1)  YES
claim_id    char(8) YES

ACCOUNTS

id  bigint(20) unsigned NO  PRI     auto_increment
user_id bigint(20) unsigned YES MUL
account_number  varchar(255)    NO  UNI
type_id bigint(20) unsigned YES MUL
description varchar(255)    NO
commission_acc_id   bigint(20) unsigned YES MUL
allow_debit varchar(255)    NO
allow_credit    varchar(255)    NO
account_status  varchar(255)    NO  MUL
creation_date   datetime    NO      0000-00-00 00:00:00

ACCOUNT_TYPES

id  bigint(20) unsigned NO  PRI     auto_increment
description varchar(255)    NO  MUL
currency    varchar(255)    NO  MUL
monthly_fee_amount  double  NO      0
monthly_fee_description varchar(255)    NO
yearly_fee_amount   double  NO      0
yearly_fee_description  varchar(255)    NO
generate_interests  varchar(255)    NO
interest_rate   double  NO      0
interest_payout_period  varchar(255)    NO
interest_payout_day char(2) NO
interest_payout_month   char(2) NO
interest_payout_hour    char(2) NO
interest_based_on   varchar(255)    NO
interest_based_on_period    varchar(255)    NO
interest_minimum_balance    double  NO      0
generate_commissions    varchar(255)    NO
commission_rate double  NO      0
commission_payout_period    varchar(255)    NO
commission_payout_day   char(2) NO
commission_payout_month char(2) NO
commission_payout_hour  char(2) NO
commission_based_on varchar(255)    NO
commission_based_on_period  varchar(255)    NO
commission_minimum_balance  double  NO      0

Below is the query we are using the below query :

```
SELECT SUM(t.amount) AS total_credit 
FROM    account_types at, 
        accounts a, 
        transactions t 
WHERE   at.currency          = var_currency 
AND     at.id                = a.type_id 
AND     (a.account_status    = 'active' 
        OR a.account_status  = 'blocked')
AND     a.id                 = t.fund_id 
AND     t.debit_credit       = var_debit_credit 
AND     t.fund_type          = 'account'
AND     t.transaction_status = 'executed';
```

which is taking 20 mins and more to get the output.

Pre-requsite from management - since it is a table of transactions we cannot archive the table we need the records to calculate the sum and not hardware changes allowed.
There are indexes on the table is also present. Represented as MUL in description.

Comment: Can you please post an EXPLAIN, and tell us what indexes exist?

Comment: These are the indexes on the tables

TRANSACTIONS
id 
debit_credit 
fund_type 
amount 
transaction_status 

ACCOUNTS
id 
type_id
commission_acc_id 
account_status

ACCOUNT_TYPES
id 
currency

Comment: Where does `var_currency` and `var_debit_credit` refer to? Are they constant?

Comment: Are there other account-Status than `active` or `blocked`? How many more?

Comment: Without an EXPLAIN, and the exact indexes you have already, we can only guess...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first, try adding an index on all the columns you need from the transaction table.

```
ALTER TABLE transaction
ADD INDEX `DebCredFundTypeTransStatus`
(`fund_id`,`debit_credit`,`fund_type`,`transaction_status`,`amount`)
```

This will reduce the number of lookups to this table to just this index, without having to go to the table itself for the data. It is important that `amount` is the rightmost part of the index.

Since `a.account_status` and `at.currency` are the only columns in their respective tables that you need to access (other than the primary key, which is included in the rightmost part of all indexes) then you should be fine with those.

The next big bottleneck would be the OR clause. Since you aren't ordering your results, we can easily slap a UNION ALL and just run it twice for each desired value of `account_status`.

```
SELECT SUM(t.amount) AS total_credit 
FROM    account_types at, 
        accounts a, 
        transactions t 
WHERE   at.currency          = var_currency 
AND     at.id                = a.type_id 
AND     a.account_status    = 'active'
AND     a.id                 = t.fund_id 
AND     t.debit_credit       = var_debit_credit 
AND     t.fund_type          = 'account'
AND     t.transaction_status = 'executed'

UNION ALL

SELECT SUM(t.amount) AS total_credit 
FROM    account_types at, 
        accounts a, 
        transactions t 
WHERE   at.currency          = var_currency 
AND     at.id                = a.type_id 
AND     a.account_status  = 'blocked'
AND     a.id                 = t.fund_id 
AND     t.debit_credit       = var_debit_credit 
AND     t.fund_type          = 'account'
AND     t.transaction_status = 'executed';
```

Those are probably the simplest and most productive changes. Try them and see if things have improved sufficiently. If not, there are other optimizations that can be applied.